# Watson Discovery: Example using query options in node.js

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I am looking for an example on how to call discovery.query in node.js.
More specifically, an example in which multiple query options are used.

The documentation mentions "query string", but I don't know how to translate that in an actual call in node.js.

Thanks in advance,
Arie

Answer (score 2):

You can see the line [#652](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/discovery/v1.js#L458) from Documentation Node SDK - Watson Developer Cloud, according to SDK doc found the method receives a `parameter` object `{}`

Then, see one example to use query string with Discovery with Nodejs.

```
require('dotenv').config({ silent: true }); 
//for access variables .env process.env.nameVariable

var DiscoveryV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/discovery/v1');


var discovery = new DiscoveryV1({
  username: process.env.DISCOVERY_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DISCOVERY_PASSWORD,
  version_date: '2017-09-01'
});

var params = {
    'query': "Sayuri",
    'environment_id': process.env.enviroment_id,
    'collection_id': process.env.collection_id,
    'configuration_id': process.env.configuration_id,
  //'passages': true, //if you want to enable passages
     return: 'text, title'
  //'highlight': true //if you want to enable highlight

}

discovery.query(params, (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      next(error);
    } else {
      console.log(results); //your query results
    }
});
```

- Reference Discovery Service [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/?node#query-collection).
- [Getting Started with Querying](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/getting-started-query.html#getting-started-with-querying) IBM Watson Discovery Service
- See more about [Query concepts](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/using.html#query-concepts).
- See more about [Query Reference](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/query-reference.html#query-reference).